# All of a sudden, many error messages with a file that worked perfectly before

Tags: errors

I am working on my thesis and use latex for the first time for this matter. So I am new to the program.
I am working with TexShop and have the following problem:
Everything with Latex worked fine for the last month. Two days ago, I started to insert some graphics as well (Bibliography and Text were already finished and everything run fine as a pdf). 
After inserting the fifth graph in the exact same way as I did the four before (and there it always worked out fine). Error message after error message popped up and since then I have tried almost any tip that I found on the internet but still cannot even open the text in the PDF file anymore.

The current error message is this:

```
Runaway argument?
{\citeauthoryear {XXXXX}
./XXX.tex:65: File ended while scanning use of \APACbibcite.
<inserted text>
             \par
l.65 \begin{document}
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going wrong here? I would be very very glad if I could get some help on this.
Thanks! 
Judith

When I delete the .aux and the .bbl file, many warnings show up, and then this: 
[image]

there is no real "error message", but the PDF still won't work

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What happens if you delete the auxiliary files (at least the `.aux` and `.bbl`) and then recompile?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Real quick: Did you maybe switch bibliography styles and/or packages that provide citation management macros? If so, does it help if you delete all aux files and start over with LaTeX and BibTeX runs?

Comment: Thank you both for your fast response! i didn't swich bibliography styles sind beginning of the month, I also didn't add any packages. When I delet the .aux and .bbl file, MANY warnings show up in this sense: Latex warning: citation 'XX' undefined on input line xxx (probably all my citations included), then also Latex Warning: reference 'fig:XXX' on page 12 undefined on input line 275. (many of those warnings as well) and then also: No file XXX.bbl. <xxx> <xxx> etc. and then [1 <./XXX.png>] ... ./XXX.tex:409: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). <to be read again> m l.409...m]{XXX.png}}

Comment: Let me know if I should formulate this clearer - I tried to shorten the console output and also tried to take out all the names of my work, so it doesn't distract here

Comment: Do you have a cite command in the caption of the new graphic?

Comment: No, @UlrikeFischer, I don't. What I do have is the same graphic twice: once in the text and once in the appendix (where all the other graphs are as well). I put this one graph in the appendix as well for the matter of comparison

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I included the last part of the console output in the original question. All other messages were warnings "only".

Comment: @Mico, I included the last part of the console output in the original question. All other messages were warnings "only".

Comment: There is an error there, the one saying `Illegal unit of measure`. What does line 409 say, the one with  something like `\includegraphics[<some options>]{o_HHW_2013_couples_live_together.png}`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. line 409 says   \centerline{\includegraphics[width=15m]{o_HHW_2013_couples_live_together.png}}

Comment: a) don't use `\centerline{...}`, instead add `\centering` the line above b) Do you really want that image to be 15 *metres* wide ... `m` is not a valid (or useful, in this case) unit, use `15cm` instead.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ha! thank you!! I changed it to cm now. I have the  \centerline{...}  command for all the graphs. should I change them all to \centering ? the graphs worked with \centerline{...} two days ago (with cm as a measure, though)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. when I let it run with cm but not yet changed it to \centering yet, the error in the console is as follows: Runaway argument= { \contentsline {figure}{ \numberline {1}{ \ignorspaces In 2013, employ \ETC../Judith's Thesis.tex:65: File ended while scanning use of  \@writefile. <inserted text>  \par l.65  \begin{document} ?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I changed all graphs to your suggested version with \centering
  \includegraphics... and the error message stays the same as written in my comment before

Comment: `\centerline` also works, I just think that `\centering` is usually recommended. The last error you show looks like it comes from the `.lof` file, try deleting that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't have a .lof file. do you mean .log file?

Comment: Ok, perhaps the `.aux` file then. I've never looked much at any of them.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you probably can't imagine what a big burden just fell from my shoulders -- the PDF is finally here again:) Thank you soo soo much! There is no error in the LaTex file anymore. But still one in BibTex: ---the literal stack isn't empty for entry ladershortgershuny while executing---line5227 of file apacite.bst (There was 1 error message) FYI: ladershortgershuny is the short name for one of my citations. I don't find any mistake in the PDF because of this error but still wanted to ask what I should do about it

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I quickly repeat my question, as I guess you didn't see it anymore as I included it only by editing my thank you comment: there is no error in the LaTex file anymore. But still one in BibTex: ---the literal stack isn't empty for entry ladershortgershuny while executing---line5227 of file apacite.bst (There was 1 error message) FYI: ladershortgershuny is the short name for one of my citations. I don't find any mistake in the PDF because of this error but still wanted to ask what I should do about it

Comment: No, I didn't see that. I don't have an answer for that though. Either completely rewrite your question to be about that error, or ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, thank you! and all the best for 2016 to you!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments